# Customer Membership Provider MVC2 and Current User in Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

I have coded custom membership provider for MVC2.

I had a specific problem in all the views and controller I was first using the following code:

```
CbMembershipProvider cb_prov_ = (CbMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
```

and in the actions to get the logged in user information I was getting the user info as follows:

```
cb_prov_.User.user_id_;
```

But the problem with this code was if I login with "user 1" and at the same time with "user 2" and going back to "user 1" screen I see "user 2" data, meaning the last logged in user data was being fetched.

Then I searched on the net and I needed to implement the getUser method of the provider. Now I did that and in each controller's action when I need current user info I am using the following call:

```
User user= cb_prov_.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Now when I tested the problem is half solved, meaning if I open IE browser and on the first tab I login with user 1 and in the second tab user 2 and go back to tab 1 then again the user 2 information is coming.

But if I login with user 1 in IE and user 2 with chrome, things seems to work ok.

Can someone please help me about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE (as with pretty much all browsers) supports a single session at a time, so there is only one session between tab 1 and tab 2, this means that when you log in user 2 in a new tab, user 1's session will be logged out as it is in the same session.  You can have a second session in IE by using the private browsing mode, same in FF and Chrome (incognito mode).

Try it with different users in Facebook or any other service, you wont be able to log into two different accounts in a singe browser session.

Comment: I understand and thanks for the input. how can I make the tab 1 user 1 log out if the user 2 in tab 2 logs in?

Comment: if you're using Forms authentication, that will happen automatically.  If you want user 1's page to automatically feedback that their session has expired (i.e. been logged out as that user) that's a bit more complex and I'm not sure how to do it, but when you log in as another user in a different tab, a page refresh of the first tab will switch the user, but I can't think that this is a particularly common use case.